# How to model the dc link voltage dynamic of the inverter fed induction machine drive in braking mode?

Tags: power-electronics, inverter, induction-motor, electric-machine, braking

I have been attempting to find the differential equation describing the dynamic of the dc link voltage of the induction machine based electric drive in braking mode.

[image]

I have started with the energy balance with the assumption that there are no losses i.e. the energy absorbed by the dc link capacitor equals the kinetic energy reduction i.e.

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\mathrm{d}E_{v_{dc}}}{\mathrm{d}t} &=& \frac{\mathrm{d}E_{k}}{\mathrm{d}t} \nonumber\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot C\cdot v^2_{dc}\right) &=& \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot J\cdot \omega^2\right)\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I have evaluated the derivatives and I have got following non-linear differential equation

$$
C\cdot v_{dc}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}v_{dc}}{\mathrm{d}t} = J\cdot\omega\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}\omega}{\mathrm{d}t}
$$

Can anybody tell me whether my considerations I have used in derivation are correct?